# How to fix "Couldn't load plugin ..." and "ImportError: No module named ..." in QGIS plugins?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

After installation of Quantum GIS (QGIS) I tried to use Table Manager Module, but I can't do it.

Here is the message:

```
Nem tudom betölteni a 'tablemanager' modult innen: ['C:/PROGRA~1/Quantum GIS Wroclaw/apps/qgis/./python', 'C:/Users/TamÃ¡s/.qgis/python', 'C:/Users/TamÃ¡s/.qgis/python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRA~1/Quantum GIS Wroclaw/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\PROGRA~1\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\bin\python27.zip', 'C:\PROGRA~1\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\apps\Python27\DLLs', 'C:\PROGRA~1\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\apps\Python27\lib', 'C:\PROGRA~1\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win', 'C:\PROGRA~1\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk', 'C:\PROGRA~1\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\apps\qgis\bin', 'C:\PROGRA~1\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\apps\Python27', 'C:\PROGRA~1\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages', 'C:\PROGRA~1\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL', 'C:\PROGRA~1\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32', 'C:\PROGRA~1\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib', 'C:\PROGRA~1\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin', 'C:\PROGRA~1\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', 'C:\PROGRA~1\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\apps\qgis\python\plugins\fTools\tools']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/Quantum GIS Wroclaw/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 117, in loadPlugin
    __import__(packageName)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/Quantum GIS Wroclaw/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 283, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named tablemanager

Python verzió:
2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]


QGIS verzió
1.7.4-Wroclaw Wroclaw, 411aff6

Python elérési út: ['C:/PROGRA~1/Quantum GIS Wroclaw/apps/qgis/./python', 'C:/Users/Tam\xc3\xa1s/.qgis/python', 'C:/Users/Tam\xc3\xa1s/.qgis/python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRA~1/Quantum GIS Wroclaw/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\\bin\\python27.zip', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\\apps\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\\apps\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\\apps\\qgis\\bin', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\\apps\\Python27', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins\\fTools\\tools']
```

Answer (score 3):

Might be a problem with the path, especially this part:

```
Tam\xc3\xa1s
```

Your user name contains special characters. This very likely causes the problems.

Try with a different user.

Comment: Yes, the problem are the special characters in the Windows username.

Comment: I had a similar problem with a Win7 username containing the German umlaut "ä" once, changing my username to a umlaut- and special-character-free one solved all problems.

Comment: @SAnderka thanks for your feedback. To show that an answer is useful, please upvote it using the arrows on the left.

Comment: Done. My thought was to wait for some feedback from Tampas, as we are still guessing here, even if it is very likely a special character issue, but upvoting probably won't hurt :)