# How to fix QGIS Plugins crashing with "NameError: name 'pyplugin_installer' is not defined"?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins

I recently switched to Windows 10 and therefor did a clean Windows and QGIS 2.10.1 Install. QGIS worked fine, I reinstalled all Plugins, that I used to have. No Problems.

Today I switched on the PC and wanted to open QGIS and was prompted with the following Error Messages. What bugs me is, that I had similar problems in my Windows 8 and QGIS 2.8 system.

The whole Python Plugin System seems to "crash". QGIS opens but all Plugins are disabled and I can't even access the Plugin-Module (where I can pick an install/uninstall plugins).

Could somebody help me with that please? A reinstall of QGIS 2.8 didn't help when I had a similar problem months ago.

The error messages (german installation):

---

> Fehler bei der Ausführung folgenden Codes: import pyplugin_installer
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in    File
>   "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISPI~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 200, in
>   loadPlugin
>       msg = msgTemplate % (packageName, "', '".join(sys.path)) UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position
>   18: ordinal not in range(128)
>
> Python-Version:
>   2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
>
> QGIS-Version:
>   2.10.1-Pisa 'Pisa', d20c5b7

---

> Fehler bei der Ausführung folgenden Codes:
>   pyplugin_installer.initPluginInstaller()
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in  NameError:
>   name 'pyplugin_installer' is not defined
>
> Python-Version:
>   2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
>
> QGIS-Version:
>   2.10.1-Pisa 'Pisa', d20c5b7
>
> Python-Pfad: ['C:/PROGRA~1/QGISPI~1/apps/qgis/./python',
>   u'C:/Users/Philipp B\xf6hme/.qgis2/python', u'C:/Users/Philipp
>   B\xf6hme/.qgis2/python/plugins',
>   'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISPI~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado-4.0.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2-py2.7.egg',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\certifi-14.05.14-py2.7.egg',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\bin\python27.zip',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\DLLs',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\bin',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win-amd64.egg',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytz-2012j-py2.7.egg',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\six-1.3.0-py2.7.egg',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg',
>   u'C:/Users/Philipp B\xf6hme/.qgis2//python', 'C:\Users\Philipp
>   B\xf6hme\.qgis2\python\plugins\DigitizingTools\tools',
>   'C:\Users\Philipp B\xf6hme\.qgis2\python\plugins\mmqgis/forms

Comment: Your plugins are by default installed here: C:\Users\Philipp\.qgis2\python\plugins so you can remove them manually simply removing the directories present there. Do this first... then restart qgis and check if python works then install plugin one by one... I suppose there is a recently installed plugin that set the system locale to ascii. There is also the way to start qgis without removing plugins, but disabling them launching qgis withg --no-plugins option.

Comment: I have just found out the reason. I used an "ö" in my Username which causes the trouble. I renamed my windows username and had to rename my user folder (thought we have the year 2015!) but now it works again. Thanks for the comment though!

Comment: @Phil Can you please post this as an answer to your question and accept it? This way others with the same issue can find the solution faster.

Comment: @Phil it can be considered a qgis issue if your system locale is set correctly. May you set again your "ö" and manually modify line 200 in C:/PROGRA~1/QGISPI~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py as: msg = unicode(msgTemplate) % (packageName, u"', '".join(sys.path)) and check again?

Comment: Unfortunately I need my system to work and can't try out to reverse the user folder name. It already cost me half of my work day to set up my cloud services, outlook and other stuff after I have changed my user folder name =(

Comment: related to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23331/how-to-fix-couldnt-load-plugin-and-importerror-no-module-named-in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just found out the reason of the python error message. I used an "ö" in my username in Windows which causes the trouble. I renamed my windows username and had to rename my user folder (thought we have the year 2015 and "ä,ö,ü" wouldn't cause trouble like this anymore!) but now it works again.

Comment: For the record, I had the same NameError: with pyplugin_installer. If was caused by one of the non ASCII character 'æøå' in a plugin file called metadata.txt